# How to implement 'User' functionality in an app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, content-management-system

This is probably a repeat. However, the other answers haven't helped me out. So, here goes.

I'm working on an application and we with need to add 'users' to it. We'll be giving the option for people to sign in with Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn. I've worked with these APIs before, however never combined them globally.

How can I maintain and manage these users that will use different services to log in. I'm confused as to how they would be stored in a database, would I need to have a different table for each different social service or is there a way to implement a table that will house all users in one place.

Comment: Dude, I agree the question is broad, however he is essentially asking only one thing, "how the hell do I store/verify users from different social services".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you're asking how to manage, store, verify users that will be logging in your application through different social services.

This is how we've implemented it through the various projects we've worked with. From the list of services you've provided we've worked only with twitter and facebook, so I can only speak about that.

Setup:

1. We have a web service that our iOS app communicates with such as when the iOS app needs to make a request call for user login the server would take the user details trying to login and gives back a response where the app would then do whats necessary.
2. We have a database stored on the server with a users table which is used to verify a user.

That being said, you need to understand whats common between most social services, or to at least know what the property is that is used by these social services to uniquely identify its users. In this case they all use email to identify users.

You'll find that when interfacing your app with these different APIs, they like to use a login session key used for unique logged in sessions.

So on your database you would store whatever details you want to save of the user, but know that you need to store atleast the username, password (encrypted), email (for identification, unique column), and login_session_key.

Just double check that linkedIn does have something like a session key that it creates when a user logs in with that method. Facebook and twitter do. Send at least the 4 main data properties needed (username, password, email, session) to the server You then follow this sort of approach:

**New user**

- If the user that is new tries to login, the server first checks the email provided even exists in the database, if it does not then you sent a response back alerting the user that the user does not exist; your app would then take them to the register screen for example.
- If the user is in the registry page, save all the details you want to store of theirs including username, password and email.

**Members**

- If the user logs in the email will exist on the server side, its an existing user so just update the session key that was sent from the app on log in if the password matches, (in some apps these session keys are used through the life cycle of the application being used, with each request sending the same session key and if at any point the session key does not match during app interaction, it can be concluded that the user has logged elsewhere on another device perhaps.
- if the password does not matches return the appropriate message.

That's about it really. We're able to store all facebook and twitter users in one table.

Comment: Thanks. Now, about this setting up a server. Will I need to buy a private domain ? Also, how do I communicate with it securely ?

Comment: That an entirely different question, a question that has been posted one to many times. Pls do some research on "setting up a web server"